# Orthogonal projection question

Tags: regression, matrix

I am working on a project (not homework) and would like to know if I am just fundamentally misguided.

Basically, let say we have some data $Y, X_1$ and $X_2$.... where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are matrices.  If I create an orthogonal projection of $X_1$ relative to $X_2$... something like this (R code; please correct me if this is misguided too)...

```
P1 <- X2  %* %  solve(t(X2) %* % X2) %*% t(X2)

X1_orth <- (diag(dim(P1)[1]) - P1) %*% X1
```

Shouldn't a simple regression of `Y ~ X1` and `Y ~ X1_orth` be the same in terms of the amount of variance in $Y$ explained by the $X$ matrix?

If someone could point me in the right direction in terms of a solution or the literature to read, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: sorry, I think I should have said it like this...                                                                                                         P1=X2(X2'X2)^-1X2                                                       
and                                                         
X1_orth = (I - P1)X1

Comment: Something to think about: What if $X_1 = X_2$, or, even $\mathcal C(X_1) = \mathcal C(X_2)$ where $\mathcal C(\cdot)$ denotes the column space?

Comment: Cardinal, thanks for the edit above and the reply.    Lets assume for the second that X1!=X2... however there may be correlation between some of their columns.  That being said, I need to think about the second part of your comment (i.e. column space).

Comment: The second part is a bit trickier depending on your linear algebra background, but the answer is the same (hint).

Comment: my background is poor; but I am trying to change that.  Currently reading "matrices for statistics" by Healy... pretty good so far.  Thanks for the hint...

Comment: Any progress? :)

Comment: Thanks for inquiring.  I have been busy with finals, and end of semester grading... etc.

Comment: I haven't had too much time to read, but would I be on the right track with what you are implying by C(X1)=C(X2) is that X1 is simply a linear function of the X2?.. is that what it means by them occupying the same column space?

Comment: I get it now (months ago, I just haven't been on this site), the simple answer to my question is no, unless the variables X1 and X2 are completely uncorrelated.  Otherwise the orthogonal projection of X1 relative to X2 will always explain less of the variance in Y as the original X1.  Duh.  Thanks for your guidance.